# Charge distribution and eletric Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I came across with the problem:

> A static charge distribution produces a radial eletric field $E=A\frac{e^{−br}}{r}\hat{e}_r$ where $A$ and $b$ are constants. Evaluate the charge density and sketch it.

If the charge distribution is given, we can evaluate the eletric field, the conversely is true? Given the eletric field I can find the charge distribution? Of couse we can just use the differential form of Gauss Law, how can I deduce the the position of the carges, for that example, the solution is a positive eletric charge at origin and a negative spherically simmetric charge in the surround space. In general, if I know the eletric field superposition how can I proceed to find the charge distribution?

Comment: What's wrong with the Poisson equation? One has to work a little bit to get the delta function for a point charge out, of course, but it's extremely easy for continuous charge densities.

Comment: The problem is in Sketch, thow can I know that the density that I've found represents  one positive charge and one symetrically sphere in surround space?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly calculate the charge distribution using the differential form of Gauss's Law and the spherical coordinates formula for divergence. I would expect a continuous charge distribution from this field, rather than a collection of point charges.

Comment: My problem is to interpret the distribution as one charge and one continuous charge.

Comment: What distribution? Did you find the charge distribution?

Comment: @EmanuelDias There's only a continuous distribution. You can find it by a direct calculation of the divergence of the given electric field.

Comment: @EmanuelDias The distribution does diverge at the origin, but it's still not a point charge. One hint: the total charge of the distribution is zero. You can tell this because the electric field falls off faster than $1/r^2.$

Comment: @nasu My above comments are also in answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry, my question was meant for the OP's comment above mine.